# Passing a list of vars to a ridge.fit() -- unhashable type?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, modeling

I have a dataset called training which was read in an manipulated using Pandas. There are about 150 variables, so I put them in a list and I want to pass them to a ridge regression; however, I get an error saying "unhashable type: list"

It's likely that I'm missing something obvious as this is my first pass using python (used to R and Stata).

Here's the code:

```
  # Variables to use (potentially) -- for dummies, one has already been taken out to avoid dummy var trap
continuous_vars = ['VehicleAge','VehOdo', 'MMRAcquisitionAuctionAveragePrice', 'MMRAcquisitionAuctionCleanPrice', 'MMRAcquisitionRetailAveragePrice', 'MMRAcquisitonRetailCleanPrice', 'MMRCurrentAuctionAveragePrice', 'MMRCurrentAuctionCleanPrice', 'MMRCurrentRetailAveragePrice', 'MMRCurrentRetailCleanPrice', 'VehBCost', 'IsOnlineSale', 'WarrantyCost', 'reliability_score', 'num_bought']
make_cats = ['BUICK', 'CADILLAC', 'CHEVROLET', 'CHRYSLER', 'DODGE', 'FORD', 'GMC', 'HONDA', 'HUMMER', 'HYUNDAI', 'INFINITI', 'ISUZU', 'JEEP', 'KIA', 'LEXUS', 'LINCOLN', 'MAZDA', 'MERCURY', 'MINI', 'MITSUBISHI', 'NISSAN', 'OLDSMOBILE', 'PLYMOUTH', 'PONTIAC', 'SATURN', 'SCION', 'SUBARU', 'SUZUKI', 'TOYOTA', 'TOYOTA SCION', 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'VOLVO']
state_cats = ['AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'FL', 'GA', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'NC', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'SC', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV']
auction_cats = ['ADESA', 'MANHEIM', 'OTHER']
trans_cats = ['AUTO']
color_cats = ['BEIGE', 'BLACK', 'BLUE', 'BROWN', 'GOLD', 'GREEN', 'GREY', 'MAROON', 'NOT AVAIL', 'ORANGE', 'OTHER', 'PURPLE', 'RED', 'SILVER', 'WHITE', 'YELLOW']
wheel_cats = ['Alloy', 'Covers', 'Special']
nat_cats = ['AMERICAN', 'OTHER', 'OTHER ASIAN', 'TOP LINE ASIAN']
size_cats =['COMPACT', 'CROSSOVER', 'LARGE', 'LARGE SUV', 'LARGE TRUCK', 'MEDIUM', 'MEDIUM SUV', 'SMALL SUV', 'SMALL TRUCK', 'SPECIALTY', 'SPORTS', 'VAN']
year_cats = ['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010_x']

all_vars = continuous_vars + make_cats + state_cats + auction_cats + trans_cats + color_cats + wheel_cats + nat_cats + size_cats + year_cats
hashable = all_vars
## Ridge Regression 
ridge_reg = Ridge(alpha=1)

ridge_reg.fit(training[hashable], training['IsBadBuy'])
```

**Update** 
I've updated the code to reflect some suggestions. Here is the new error message:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1068, in _convert_to_indexer
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['reliability_score' 'num_bought' 'BUICK' 'CADILLAC' 'CHEVROLET' 'CHRYSLER'\n 'DODGE' 'FORD' 'GMC' 'HONDA' 'HUMMER' 'HYUNDAI' 'INFINITI' 'ISUZU' 'JEEP'\n 'KIA' 'LEXUS' 'LINCOLN' 'MAZDA' 'MERCURY' 'MINI' 'MITSUBISHI' 'NISSAN'\n 'OLDSMOBILE' 'PLYMOUTH' 'PONTIAC' 'SATURN' 'SCION' 'SUBARU' 'SUZUKI'\n 'TOYOTA' 'TOYOTA SCION' 'VOLKSWAGEN' 'VOLVO' 'AR' 'AZ' 'CA' 'CO' 'FL' 'GA'\n 'IA' 'ID' 'IL' 'IN' 'KY' 'LA' 'MA' 'MD' 'MI' 'MN' 'MO' 'MS' 'NC' 'NE' 'NH'\n 'NJ' 'NM' 'NV' 'NY' 'OH' 'OK' 'OR' 'PA' 'SC' 'TN' 'TX' 'UT' 'VA' 'WA' 'WV'\n 'ADESA' 'MANHEIM' 'OTHER' 'AUTO' 'BEIGE' 'BLACK' 'BLUE' 'BROWN' 'GOLD'\n 'GREEN' 'GREY' 'MAROON' 'NOT AVAIL' 'ORANGE' 'OTHER' 'PURPLE' 'RED'\n 'SILVER' 'WHITE' 'YELLOW' 'Alloy' 'Covers' 'Special' 'AMERICAN' 'OTHER'\n 'OTHER ASIAN' 'TOP LINE ASIAN' 'COMPACT' 'CROSSOVER' 'LARGE' 'LARGE SUV'\n 'LARGE TRUCK' 'MEDIUM' 'MEDIUM SUV' 'SMALL SUV' 'SMALL TRUCK' 'SPECIALTY'\n 'SPORTS' 'VAN' '2001' '2002' '2003' '2004' '2005' '2006' '2007' '2008'\n '2009' '2010_x'] not in index"
```

Comment: I notice that there are some `\n` in the KeyError output. You might look into where those are coming from.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a temp just to hold the result, can you edit your question with the result of `print(all_vars)`, you seem to have embedded `\n`'s for Chrysler, Jeep, 2008 ..etc.

Comment: Also can you print the output from `training.info()` or `training.columns` it's possible that your column names may have embedded `\n` or not match one of the columns you are trying, you could just try each grouping each turn to see if they work as a column selection

Comment: Rather than update this question with another question, why not accept the answer that helped you, and make a new question? Better for everyone that way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did was create a list of lists, you want to concatenate them all:

```
all_vars = continuous_vars+ make_cats+ state_cats+ auction_cats+ trans_cats+ color_cats+ wheel_cats+ nat_cats+ size_cats+ year_cats
```

This will then select the feature columns from pandas correctly

Compare the following:

```
In [84]:

[auction_cats, wheel_cats]
Out[84]:
[['ADESA', 'MANHEIM', 'OTHER'], ['Alloy', 'Covers', 'Special']]
In [85]:

auction_cats+wheel_cats
Out[85]:
['ADESA', 'MANHEIM', 'OTHER', 'Alloy', 'Covers', 'Special']
```

Comment: So I fixed that and used Haseeb ur Rahman's suggestion and I'm getting a new error. I've updated my post with the new code and error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem a few days ago. Turns out you cannot use list type as keys in a dictionary. I got around this problem by assigning the list element to a new variable and used that variable as the key.

```
hashableVar = all_vars
training[hashableVar]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but it may be because of another unrelated error. I've updated my code with the new error message. Thanks!